# Select specific name and input type Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery keyboard from Mottie. I want this keyboard to be shown only with `name` attribute equal to "email" and the input `type` to be a text field.

The code below doesnt work for me.

```
$("input[name!='email' type='text']").keyboard({ //my code here });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect selector for targeting input element. Use:

```
$("input[name=email][type=text]")
```

or

```
$("input:text[name=email]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your [attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector format is not correct , use the following

```
$("input[name=email][type=text]").keyboard({ //my code here });
```

Comment: Sorry Milind was first to answer.